# NumPy - index of highest average

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following values:

```
grade_list = [[99 73 97 98] [98 71 70 99]]
student_ids = [521 597 624 100]
```

Each array in the `grade_list` represents a list of grades for each student (student #521 grades are 99, 98, student #597 grades are 73, 71, and so on..)

My goal is to return the student ID of the one with the highest average grade (should be `521` since the average is 98.5 which is the highest)

I have tried this:

```
def find_student_with_max_avg(grade_list, student_ids):
    mean_grades = np.mean(grade_list, axis=1)
    best_student_index = student_ids[mean_grades.argmax()]
    return best_student_index
```

which returned `521`, but I have tried to play with the `grade_list and I see that even when I set this student grades to 0, it still return` 521`.

not sure how to get the student ID of the best student, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the mean along the wrong axis:

```
>>> np.mean(grade_list, axis=1)
array([91.75, 84.5 ])
```

Change the axis, and check that you get as many mean values as there are student IDs.

```
>>> np.mean(grade_list, axis=0)
array([98.5, 72. , 83.5, 98.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
import numpy as np

grade_list = [[99,73,97,98] ,[98,71,70,99]]
student_ids = [521,597,624,100]

# axis 0 is row-wise, and 1 is column-wise
student_ids[np.array(grade_list).mean(axis=0).argmax()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Counter for this.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np


grade_list = [[99, 73, 97, 98], [98, 71, 70, 99]] 
student_ids = [521, 597, 624, 100]                                     

c = Counter() 
for i,n in enumerate(student_ids): 
    c.update({n:np.mean([item[i] for item in grade_list])}) 
                                                                   

c.most_common()                                                        
[(521, 98.5), (100, 98.5), (624, 83.5), (597, 72.0)]
```

As you see, you get 2 best students in this case.

```
In [17]: best_score = c.most_common(1)[0][1]                                    

In [18]: best_score                                                             
Out[18]: 98.5

In [19]: best_students = [k for k,v in c.items() if v == best_score]            

In [20]: best_students                                                          
Out[20]: [521, 100]
```